# verify the login details based on the HashMap (Create a map with user name and password) in the servlet

Tags: java, servlets, dictionary

i am very much new to Java. I know the question is very basic but please can anyone reply. I know how to verify using mySQL but unable to do with using hashmap.

> verify the login details based on the Map (Create a map with user name
>   & password) in the servlet.

```
package expenses;

public class ValidateServlet extends HttpServlet{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1563760349997052176L;

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("lit", "lit");
        map.put("rajesh","rajesh");
        map.put("souji", "souji");

        String strUserName = request.getParameter("username");
           String strPassword = request.getParameter("pwd");
           String strErrMsg = null;
           try {
               if
           }

    }
```

Comment: Where's your code, what have you tried already?

Comment: yeah..

public class ValidateServlet extends HttpServlet{  
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1563760349997052176L;
 
 @Override
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
 map.put("lithusha", "lithusha");
 map.put("rajesh","rajesh");
 map.put("souji", "souji");                        String strUserName = request.getParameter("username");
String strPassword = request.getParameter("pwd");
String strErrMsg = null;
     try {
      if
     }
  
 }

Comment: Please don't paste code in a comment.  Instead, edit your question and paste your code in a Markdown-formatted code block.  (See the FAQs for more information.)  A detailed, properly formatted question is likely to get you more help.

Comment: Thanks i will do that...Sorry I am new just created this account..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to see how to add and retrieve objects from a HashMap

```
 @Override
        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            String strUserName = request.getParameter("username");
            String strPassword = request.getParameter("pwd");

            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("usernamekey", strUserName);
            map.put("passwordkey", strPassword);

            if(map.get("usernamekey").equals("rajesh") && 
                    map.get("passwordkey").equals("souji")){ // use equalsIgnoreCase if needed
                // login success
            }

        }
```